# Facebook "me" node information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get my information with the `Graph API node` "me" using the Graph API Explorer to make some tests.

If I use the **version v2.5(latest)** only `"id"` and `"name"` fields are retrieved.

But if I use the **v2.3 or earlier versions**, more information like `"birthday"`, `"first_name"`, `"gender"`, `"last_name"` are retrieved.

I need all information like older version but want to use the latest one. What must I do different?

Comment: Maybe there are permissions needed to be allowed?

Comment: But I'm using the same access token, when use version `v2.3` return every field. I don't think that is a permission problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called "Declarative Fields" and came with v2.4. You now have to specify the fields you want to get, or you will only get the id and name:

```
/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,birthday
```

Of course you have to authorize the user with `user_birthday` to get his birthday.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4